# r shiny - cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r, shiny

I've got this annoying error that comes up when running my shiny app. First, the code:

```
df2 <- c(2012,2013,2014,2015)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     sliderInput("year_range",
                  "Select Years:",
                  min = 2012,
                  max = 2019,
                  value = c(2012,2019),
                  ticks = FALSE
     )
    )
    mainPanel( 
      # stuff goes in here
    )
   )
 )

 server <- function(input, output) {
   # put years into variables
   show_years_l <- renderText(input$year_range[1])
   show_years_h <- renderText(input$year_range[2])

   # update list based on years selected
   trim_years <- df2 %>% filter(between(V1, show_years_l, show_years_h))
 }
 
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have read over these links but cannot logically apply it to my situation:

[R shiny cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991428/r-shiny-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double)

[R error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655967/r-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double)

I've tried putting as.numeric for the show_years_l and show_years_h values but I get the same error.

```
 filter(between(V1, as.numeric(show_years_l), as.numeric(show_years_h)))
```

I've also tried typing in the values as numbers ie- 2013, 2014 in the filter statement but the same error shows.

```
 filter(between(V1, 2013, 2014))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `renderText` here? You don't seem to be acruallt rendering any text. How about just `trim_years <- df2 %>% filter(between(V1, input$year_range[1], input$year_range[2]))`. but still, `trim_years` needs to be inside a reactive environment and it currently is not. Have you gone through a Shiny tutorial or anything anything yet? A good place to start is with the videos here: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con-2016/. especially the introduction to reactivity.

Comment: Running the `ui` code returns `argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default`.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, this unfortunately returns the same error. I did run through the tutorials, just adding bits and pieces at a time. I can't find information easily on what I am trying to acheive.

Comment: @RonakShah I left mainPanel out deliberately as I deemed it irrelevant, that is my mistake I will fix the example code.

Comment: @binga30 It returns the exact same error? Make sure to remove the `show_years_l ` and `show_years_h` values since we use the input directly in the filter. But what do you even want to do `trim_years` anyway? You don't have it going anywhere in your code. I can't imagine what tutorial told you to use `renderText()` without a matching `textOutput()` in the UI. You don't use things that come from a render() function as input to a calculation. Perhaps you are thinking of `reactiveVal()` This seems very incomplete and it's not clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @MrFlick I forgot to delete show_years_l, getting a new error now:
Can't access reactive value 'year_range' outside of reactive consumer.
Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observer()?
Input `..1` is `between(Year, input$year_range[1], input$year_range[2])`.

I'm trying to use trim_years to only grab the values from df2 that the sliderInput range has selected. the variable trim_years will be used to plot but I haven't reached that point yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

df2 <- tibble(years = c(2012,2013,2014,2015))

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("year_range",
                    "Select Years:",
                    min = 2012,
                    max = 2019,
                    value = c(2012, 2019),
                    ticks = FALSE)),
        mainPanel(tableOutput('table'))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
     
    output$table <-  renderTable({
    filter(df2, years >= input$year_range[1], years <= input$year_range[2])
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran this example and it worked perfect. I was able to take the filter statement and use it in my renderPlot. It was my fault my previous filter statement was outside the renderPlot function, but I am still unsure why I got the: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double' error, when using "between()"